# Uncaught ScriptError: Invalid argument: EVENT_HANGOUT

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception

This error is received when I try to update a calendar event's title and description. The strange thing is it works on one calendar and not on the other.

Here is a code example

```
function makeAppointment(eventID, person, calendarID){
  Logger.log("eventID:", eventID);
  Logger.log("userFolder: " + person);
  Logger.log("calendarID: " + calendarID);

  var userFolder = findFolder(person);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  var event = calendar.getEventSeriesById(eventID);
  var appointments = getAppointments(true, calendarID);
  try {

  event.setTitle("Interviewee: " + person);
  event.setDescription(userFolder.getUrl());

  return appointments;
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log("There was an issue with setting interview");

  }
  return appointments;
}
```

The makeAppointment function is called from the java script side where the relevant information is passed in. But it throws an error on the client side browser console image attached. There are 59 events present on the calendar that creates this issue and 2 on the one that doesn't, I find that to be the only difference between the two.

[image: console log error]

Thanks for any help provided in solving this issue

Comment: The error is coming from the calendar application.

Comment: I know, but I don't know why it's throwing the error and how to fix it so it works. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Would have to see where in `CalendarApp` it's happening, and what variable it's complaining about.

Comment: I figured it out. So apparently if the event has a hangouts session added to it, it throws this error. However if not it works. So it might be that it's has the error suggest. a "EVENT_HANGOUT". I didn't know events and hangout events are different.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the type of event. When creating an event, if there is a video call option present for that event, it will throw an error when updating. Removing the video call option will resolve the issue.